# Increasing duration of image scaling animation (CGAffineTransformMakeScale)

Tags: iphone, image, size, zooming, scale

I know the code to make an image grow in size is:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(5f, 5f);
```

But what can I add to this to make that effect take several seconds?

The intended effect is for it to appear as though the app user is slowing getting close to or zooming in on a painting on a wall, so I want to start with the image at a small size and then have it slowly get larger over the course of, maybe, 3 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap it in an animation block like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 ///< or however many seconds you want
                 animations:^{
                     imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(5f, 5f);
                 }];
```

Comment: What if I would like to make it immediate without animation?